# reference table value not displayed in Yii GridView

Tags: gridview, yii

I have an problem to display reference table value in cGridView.

Here is the relation.  each user have multiple images and each image has single user.

UserImages.php   model

```
public function relations()
{
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(
        'user'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO,'Users','user_id')
    );
}
```

Users.php Model

```
public function relations()

{

    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related

    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.

        return array(
            'images'=>array(self::HAS_MANY,'UserImages','user_id')
        );
}
```

User image grid view

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(

'id'=>'user-images-grid',

'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),

'filter'=>$model,

'columns'=>array(

    'image_id',

    'user_id',

    array('name'=>'username', 'value'=>'$data->user->username', 'header'=>'User Name'),

    array('name'=>'filename','type'=>'raw','value'=>array($this,'gridThumb')),


    'caption',

    array(
        'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
        'template'=>'{update} | {delete}',
        'updateButtonImageUrl'=>false,
        'deleteButtonImageUrl'=>false,          
    ),
),

));
```

But every time i got this error:
**Property "UserImages.username" is not defined.**

Is there anything wrong i am doing ? please help.

Note :  both table contains user_id column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need both name and value in attribute. Change

```
 array('name'=>'username', 'value'=>'$data->user->username', 'header'=>'User Name'),
```

to

```
array('value'=>'isset($data->user->username)?$data->user->username:""', 'header'=>'User Name'),
```

it should solve your problem

See http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDataColumn#name-detail for more details

Comment: Thanks but it is not working.  now i got this error :  http://awesomescreenshot.com/0692yd9q7c    Any help would be thankful ?

Comment: it means you have some rows without user_id therefore $data->user object is not set, and therefore property of non object you can modify value as above to fix the problem

Comment: how can i print all rows array dispalyed in GridView ?

Comment: $model->search() returns CActiveDataProvider you can loop through the DataProvider, easier way is to check in phpmyadmin or similar tool. If you check object presence using as i changed above it should work irrespective

Comment: Hey thank you very much, your last fix works. You're right there were some records which do not contain user related values.    Once again thanks